# Alexa lamda get underlying resolved slot value in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have an intent called "Get Status" this has a `SHOULDCHANGESTATUS` slot which is of type `YES_NO`

I have the following logic in my Lambda which worked fine using the text Test facility in the Alexa Dev tools.

```
let changeStatusSlot = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.SHOULDCHANGESTATUS.value;      

if(changeStatusSlot === 'no'){
    return statusFunctions.closureMessage(handlerInput);
}
```

When I'm testing this using the actual device the word "No" is coming through as "Naw".

The Yes_No slot has "naw" as an acceptable type for "No", so I should be able to handle this.

I need to change the selector on the `SHOULDCHANGESTATUS` slot to get me the underlying value for this slot, which should be NO but I cant get it to work.

I have tried:

```
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.SHOULDCHANGESTATUS.Resolution.Authorities[0].Values[0].Value.Name
```

but I get an undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close, the solution was:

```
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots['SHOULDCHANGESTATUS'].resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name;
```

This object structure helped me find what i needed:

[image]